# What is a DFS-Forest Component?

Tags: algorithm

I know how Depth First Search works and how to implement it, but I keep seeing DFS-Forest Component being referenced in my textbook, and I'm not entirely sure what it means. I know that a component of a graph is a subgraph disconnected from the other components. So what is a DFS-Forest Component?

Comment: Can you provide a quote or two from your text book? I imagine the term DFS-Forest Component is just talking about a subgraph, which you mentioned in your question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this University of Edinburgh's paper](https://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/inf2b/algnotes/note10.pdf):

> A DFS starting at some vertex v explores the graph by building up a
>   tree that contains all vertices that are reachable from v and all
>   edges that are used to reach these vertices. We call this tree a DFS
>   tree. A complete DFS exploring the full graph (and not only the part
>   reachable from a given vertex v) builds up a collection of trees, or
>   forest, called a DFS forest.

Comment: How so specifically?

Comment: I think what the quote means is that each DFS Forest created as a result of the Depth First Search on a specific root node is a separate component of the the same DFS Graph (where a DFS graph contains all of the possible forests starting from different root nodes)?

Comment: Is that what it means?

Comment: @ChrisRisley I don't think so. The quotation says that a full search (DFS) of the graph builds a DFS forest. So then presumably the root nodes are a part of the DFS forest and not resulting in different DFS forests. So then I would take it as meaning each set of root nodes is a forest. (a subset of the full forest, but perhaps forests nonetheless? as for the components I have no clue)

Answer (score 3):

I was overthinking it:

A DFS-Forest Component is any set of nodes within the DFS-Forest that are strongly connected (a path between all pairs of vertices in the component exists). In an undirected graph, I'd imagine this means that every node is a part of the same component, but in a directed graph this isn't necessarily the case.